# How could I terminate my program on c++ by pressing the special character '!'?

Tags: c++

So I am making a c++ calculator for my class assignment and I need to be able to exit the program by pressing the special character <kbd>!</kbd>. I have tried a do/while loop, a while loop and even the `GetAsyncKeyState` from the library windows.h, but nothing seems to work. The main function of my program would look something like this:

```
   int main()
    {
       Stack<char> a;
       char * expression;
       expression=new char[30];
       char * temp;
       temp=new char[30];
       int result=0;
       bool flag=true;

       cout<<"Enter an Infix Expression:";
       cin>>expression;
       //some more code//
       .....
    }
```

Is there a way to whenever the special character <kbd>!</kbd> is pressed, store it in the char variable expression and exit the program? or what can I do to exit the program whenever that key is pressed?

Comment: Is your program allowed to be multithreaded?  If it is, write it as two threads: one to poll the keyboard, check for ! and add items to a queue, the other to parse the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I'm new here, I don't know if I can write code in comment, so I just write a new answer

```
while(true)
{    
    cout<<"Enter an Infix Expression:";
    cin>>expression;
    if(string(expression).at(0) == '!')
       break;

    ... //do your things here
}
exit(0);
//try this, and tell me if it works. I think this is better than the last one
```

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot, I had tried a while(true) loop before but not using string(expression), thanks a lot it runs perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to implement your own "read stuff from stdin" function that would watch for `!` and act accordingly (perhaps by calling `exit()` directly, or throwing an exception). I'd provide more info, but your question doesn't ask for specifics. Also, how are you parsing expressions? I ask beause `!` happens to be the factorial operator, which you users might enter.

Comment: I did not really ask for specifics because I do not know what other methods I could use to do this, the point of the program is basically to be a calculator to determined reverse plosh notation, based on the infix expression which is stored in the char expression. However the program is supossed to be able to terminate once the user presses '!'. However, how would the stdin function work in this case? If you could be as kind as to explain it a a bit for me, I would greatly apreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
   if(strcmp(expression, "!") == 0)
        exit(0);
```

Comment: I did try it, but it did not work, instead, the program just opened without even asking to enter the infix expression. Was there a specific place where I am supossd to put this?

Comment: Well, it is obviously after cin. I'm sure you know that. Try this one:    string(expression).compare("!") == 0

Comment: yeah sorry, just wanted to make sure I was using it correctly, the one you just gave me works, but only once, I would need the program to be able to loop until the '!' is pressed.